# For some reason my background is not high resolutions until the end?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

At the bottom are two divs(`bottom stanga and bottom dreapta`)`

Look at the picture below to understand what happens in high resolution.

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="continut">
<div style="height:60%;" class="carousel">[image-carousel category="test"]</div>
<div class="banner-mobile">The top div</div>
<div class="bottom stanga">bottom left</div>
<div class="bottom dreapta">bottom right</div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.bottom {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
height:40%;

}
.stanga {
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS1-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
.dreapta {
   background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS2-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The problem is only on high resolution ... can you tell me please what is good in the way we think?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just checked in Firfox 39.0 and it looks just fine. http://imgur.com/Pi2T8bS

Comment: hmm I wonder where is the problem?

Comment: Can you define high resolution? Do you mean large screens or high density in this case?

Comment: The problem happens to me when I change the dimension  of the browser. I can see that there is a js which changes the height of the div under the comment  `.entry-header `. I think the calculation of the height is not correct.